# How to check if an element of a list has been visited or not

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm

I am trying to create a list of complete set of dependencies (recursive traversal of dependencies) for a given Jenkins plugin. I have tried this below code snippet.

```
from requests import Session

session = Session()

deps = []

def get_deps():
    user_input = input('Enter a jenkins plug-in name: ')
    print(user_input)
    url = "https://plugins.jenkins.io/api/plugin/"+user_input+""
    reqs = session.get(url)
    response = reqs.json()
    for item in response['dependencies']:
        print(item['name'])
        deps.append(item['name'])
    print(deps)
    
    for elem in deps:
        url = "https://plugins.jenkins.io/api/plugin/"+elem+""
        reqs = session.get(url)
        response = reqs.json()
        for item in response['dependencies']:
            deps.append(item['name'])
        print(deps)
        

get_deps()
```

This will create an infinite loop. How to ensure that a list element which has been visited before is not acted upon once again?

Comment: put stuff you visited in a set, check set before visiting? You currently do not recurse into get_deps - so it is currently a non-problem?

Comment: @PatrickArtner I have called get_deps(). It is at bottom of the snippet

Comment: @PatrickArtner Can you show an example on the sets? Python is new to me

Comment: Soo ... you are good enough to write this code, but can not add using a set of ressources you visited? Sorry. I am out.

Answer (score 0):

This way, when all the elements have been visited, everything from `lst1` will be transferred to `lst2`:

```
lst1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
if lst1:
# do something
lst2.append(lst1.pop(lst1.index(3))) # move the element (in this example, 3) from lst1 to lst2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the recursive way:

```
from requests import Session

session = Session()

deps = []
# name = "dotnet-as-script"

def get_deps(name):
    if name not in deps:
        deps.append(name)
        url = f"https://plugins.jenkins.io/api/plugin/{name}"
        reqs = session.get(url)
        response = reqs.json()
        for item in response['dependencies']:
            print(item['name'])
            deps.append(item['name'])
            get_deps(item['name'])


name = input("Please enter the plugin name:")
get_deps(name)

print(deps)
```

Each time `get_deps` is called, it checks if the dependency is already in the list. If not, it gets the deps for that plugin and for each of them, calls the same function again.

Your code produced an endless loop, because it was extending the list without checking for duplicates, it was iterating over.